# How to Push For Loop in Object inside useState “React”

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, use-state

I need to push Object in useState:

```
const [getData, setGetData] = useState({});

const data = {
    name: ["My Name"],
    age: ["33 Years"],
    address: ["My Address"]
}

useEffect(() => {
    if (data) {
        for (const input in data) {
            if (Error.hasOwnProperty(input)) {
                setGetData({...getData, [input]: data[input][0]});
            }
        }
    }
}, [data]);

console.log(getData);
```

And i try to show it but i found the "getData" is empty {}

Comment: I believe there is a bit of confusion about react hooks and some basic React knowledge. 
Try to start with the basic example and then build from there: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html

Comment: it is true what @ThalesKenne says that there is some lack of knowledge when it comes to javaScript and React hooks. So I will explain this to you and I hope that you learn from this and not just copy and paste the code because then you will not learn why your code will not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you know what kind of keys your object will have then you can specify it

```
const [getData, setGetData] = useState({}); // change this to useReducer instead?
```

so instead of your code you can use useReducer(look that up on reactjs.org), but since you are using useState I will go with that.

```
const [getData, setGetData] = useState({name:'',age:'',address:''});
```

What you are trying to do here is creating an object that has three keys `name`, `age`, and `address`. The problem I see here is instead of adding a string as the value you are adding an array with the string `"My Name"`. I don't know if you want the user to have multiple names or ages. The address part I can sort of understand, but normally you have a primary address and then a secondary address.
So I would recommend that you look up data structuring.

```
const data = {
  name: ["My Name"], // 1
  age: ["33 Years"],
  address: ["My Address"]
}
```

This is how I would structure the data

```
const data = {
  name: "My Name", // 1
  age: 33, // I would change this to a date such as 1999-12-01 instead of just '33'
  primaryAddress: "My Address",
  secondaryAddress: "My Address",
}
```

Then we come to the second part

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (data) {  // You should move this to a function instead, much cleaner
        for (const input in data) { // If you have an object you don't need to loop over them and add each key and value pare.
            if (Error.hasOwnProperty(input)) {
                setGetData({...getData, [input]: data[input][0]});
            }
        }
    }
}, [data]);
```

I would just do it something like this :

```
useEffect(() => {
  setGetData(data)
},[data])
```